# Search "not" tag not working?

Tags: bug, search

I am wanting search like this

newest 0 answer questions with [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) tag or [git](/questions/tagged/git) tag **and without [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag**

I tried

[stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ffmpeg+or+git+-php?tab=newest](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ffmpeg+or+git+-php?tab=newest)

The page shows

[ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) or [git](/questions/tagged/git) not [php](/questions/tagged/php)

as expected but php tagged questions are still showing up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+%2B%5Bffmpeg%5D+-%5Bphp%5D

Comment: @Dynamic apologies, I also want or git tag. See question edit.

Comment: You would have to do that in two separate searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackExchange site query for newest 0 answer questions with ffmpeg tag or git tag and without php tag:

1. Use this query in search:

   [answers:0 [ffmpeg] or [git] -[php]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%20answers:0%20%5Bffmpeg%5D%20or%20%5Bgit%5D%20-%5Bphp%5D)
2. Select the "Newest Tab".
   [image]